# command not binding properly

Tags: wpf, binding, command

Please find the code used for simple binding.

Xaml code:

```
Button Command="{Binding BoldCommand}"
```

C# code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : RibbonWindow
{
    public BoldCommand BoldCommand
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
        BoldCommand = new BoldCommand();
        DataContext = BoldCommand;
    }


}

public class BoldCommand : ICommand
{

    public BoldCommand()
    {

    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to give us more details. do you get any error? any exception?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `BoldCommand` in your `DataContext` does not have a `BoldCommand` property.

The major problem you are going to have is that you have conjoined your View and ViewModel. Replace your `MainWindow` code with the following and it should work.

```
public partial class MainWindow : RibbonWindow
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();                    
    DataContext = new MainViewModel();
  }
}

public class MainViewModel
{
  public MainViewModel()
  {
    BoldCommand = new BoldCommand();
  }

  public BoldCommand BoldCommand { get; set; }
}
```